# Using Clip function through ArcPy gives ERROR 000725

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000210, error-000725, error-000354

I am having trouble running a clip function with arcpy based on this  [tutorial](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/256).

I run the code below and get an error message:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\USA.gdb\\USA.gdb"
featureClasslist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
clipFeature = "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb\\Alabama.gdb\\StateBoundary"

for featureClass in featureClasslist:
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClass, clipFeature, "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb\\test"+featureClass)
```

error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3fb4ae64a159> in <module>()
      6 
      7 for featureClass in featureClasslist:
----> 8     arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClass, clipFeature, "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb\\test"+featureClass)
      9 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py in Clip(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance)
    165         return retval
    166     except Exception as e:
--> 167         raise e
    168 
    169 @gptooldoc('Select_analysis', None)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py in Clip(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance)
    162     from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
    163     try:
--> 164         retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Clip_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance), True)))
    165         return retval
    166     except Exception as e:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    494         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    495         if callable(val):
--> 496             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    497         else:
    498             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\dresc\Desktop\Classes\05_Arc_Scripts\3.1_data\Alabama.gdb\testBoundaries.shp.shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Clip)
```

It seems like the operation is adding an extra ".shp" to the file path, but I can't figure out why or how to remove it.

Edit:

I realize I added the unnecessary "test" text in the last file path, however, I still get an error message after removing "test":

-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-01d95e723ae1> in <module>()
      6 
      7 for featureClass in featureClasslist:
----> 8     arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClass, clipFeature, "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb"+featureClass+"1")
      9 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py in Clip(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance)
    165         return retval
    166     except Exception as e:
--> 167         raise e
    168 
    169 @gptooldoc('Select_analysis', None)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py in Clip(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance)
    162     from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
    163     try:
--> 164         retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Clip_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, cluster_tolerance), True)))
    165         return retval
    166     except Exception as e:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    494         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    495         if callable(val):
--> 496             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    497         else:
    498             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset C:\Users\dresc\Desktop\Classes\05_Arc_Scripts\3.1_data\Alabama.shp already exists.
Failed to execute (Clip).
```

Comment: I realize I added the unnecessary "test" text in the last file path, however, I still get an error message:

Comment: Try arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True. Naming of your folder is bad btw.

Comment: Is it that there are dots in the folder title or is there more?

Comment: Please revise your question so that it only contains the latest code snippet that you are using, and also only the error message that results from that code.  Now that you have an answer be careful that any editing you do to your question does not invalidate that.  If it does then think about accepting the answer, and starting a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Dont name a folder with dots in the name. Try using os.path.join:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\USA.gdb\\USA.gdb"

clipFeature = "C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb\\Alabama.gdb\\StateBoundary"

for featureClass in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    outfc = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\dresc\\Desktop\\Classes\\05_Arc_Scripts\\3.1_data\\Alabama.gdb", "test_"+featureClass)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=featureClass, clip_features=clipFeatures, 
                        out_feature_class=outfc)
```

Comment: I changed the dots to "_", I get an error saying "clipFeatures" is not defined. I think you meant "clipFeature?" Removing the s, I still get the invalid character error.